# asp table returning 0 rows on save

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form with a table, a cancel button and a save button. The last column in the table is editable. The save button saves the edits to the last column. The problem I am having is when I save, the table posts back as having 0 rows in the SaveButton_ServerClick method.

HTML:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="xxxxxx.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxxxx.xxx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Table id="SettingsTable" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Table>
        <asp:Button id="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button id="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save"></asp:Button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#:

```
        const string CONFIG_SET_ID = "ConfigurationSetId";
        const string CONFIG_SET_NAME = "ConfigurationSetName";
        const string CONFIG_SET_DESC = "ConfigurationSetDescription";
        const string APP_NAME = "AppName";
        const string APP_ID = "AppId";
        const string SET_CAT = "SettingCategory";
        const string SET_DESC = "SettingDescription";
        const string SET_CAT_ID = "SettingCategoryId";
        const string TITLE = "title";

        const int CONFIG_SET_CELL = 0;
        const int APP_NAME_CELL = 1;
        const int SET_CAT_CELL = 2;
        const int SETTINGKEY_CELL = 3;
        const int SETTINGVALUE_CELL = 4;

        static Dictionary<string, ConfigurationDictionary> _cfgDics = new Dictionary<string, ConfigurationDictionary>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AppCfg.AppName = "xxxxx";
            AppCfg.Initialize();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                LoadSettings();

            SaveButton.Click += SaveButton_ServerClick;
            CancelButton.Click += CancelButton_ServerClick;
        }

        /// ADDING THIS FIXED THE POSTBACK PROBLEM.
        void CancelButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSettings();
        }

        void SaveButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TableRow row in SettingsTable.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[SETTINGVALUE_CELL].Controls[0].GetType().Equals(typeof(TextBox)))
                {
                    string appId = row.Cells[APP_NAME_CELL].Attributes[APP_ID];
                    string settingKey = row.Cells[SETTINGKEY_CELL].Text;
                    string settingValue = ((TextBox)row.Cells[SETTINGVALUE_CELL].Controls[0]).Text;

                    if (_cfgDics.ContainsKey(appId) && _cfgDics[appId][settingKey].Value != settingValue)
                        _cfgDics[appId][settingKey] = settingValue;
                }
            }


            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            LoadSettings();
        }

        void CancelButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSettings();
        }


        private void LoadSettings()
        {
            //foreach (ConfigurationDictionary dic in _cfgDics.Values)
            //    dic.Dispose();

            //_cfgDics.Clear();
            SettingsTable.Rows.Clear();

            // Build Settings table
            // Build Header row
            TableRow headerRow = new TableRow();
            headerRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Config Set" });
            headerRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Application" });
            headerRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Category" });
            headerRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Setting Key" });
            headerRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Setting Value" });
            SettingsTable.Rows.Add(headerRow);

            IniFileEditor xxxIni = new IniFileEditor();
            string dbConnString = xxxIni.ReadValue(ConfigurationDictionary.SECKEY, ConfigurationDictionary.SETTING_DB_KEY);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbConnString))
            {
                // Build each setting
                using (DatabaseAccess dba = new DatabaseAccess(dbConnString))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from AllSettings"))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = dba.GetSqlReader(cmd))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        TableRow row = new TableRow();
                        string appId = string.Empty;

                        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = reader[CONFIG_SET_NAME].ToString() });
                        row.Cells[CONFIG_SET_CELL].Attributes[CONFIG_SET_ID] = reader[CONFIG_SET_ID].ToString();
                        row.Cells[CONFIG_SET_CELL].Attributes[TITLE] = reader[CONFIG_SET_DESC].ToString();

                        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = reader[APP_NAME].ToString() });
                        appId = reader[APP_ID].ToString();
                        row.Cells[APP_NAME_CELL].Attributes[APP_ID] = appId;
                        row.Cells[APP_NAME_CELL].Attributes[TITLE] = string.Format("AppId:\t{0} \r\nMachine:\t{1} \r\nIPAddress:\t{2}",
                                                                       reader[APP_ID],
                                                                       reader["MachineName"],
                                                                       reader["MachineAddress"]);

                        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = reader[SET_CAT].ToString() });
                        row.Cells[SET_CAT_CELL].Attributes[SET_CAT_ID] = reader[SET_CAT_ID].ToString();

                        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = reader["SettingKey"].ToString() });
                        row.Cells[SETTINGKEY_CELL].Attributes[TITLE] = reader[SET_DESC].ToString();

                        TextBox valueTextbox = new TextBox();
                        valueTextbox.Text = reader["SettingValue"].ToString();
                        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                        row.Cells[SETTINGVALUE_CELL].Controls.Add(valueTextbox);

                        if (!_cfgDics.ContainsKey(appId))
                            _cfgDics.Add(appId, new ConfigurationDictionary(appId));

                        SettingsTable.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The LoadSettings method is not called on the IsPostBack so the SettingsTable is empty if you don't retrieve it from the Session or the ViewState

Comment: I added the saving of session state but the values I change in the web UI are not posted back. Am I going about the design of this all wrong?

Comment: After using another answer, Seano666 was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the dynamic controls every time in the PreInit event, that is the only way ViewState will ever get applied on Post-Back.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSettings();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon post back the table data been lost. so please keep the table data in the sessionstate or viewstate.